# Getting updates via xively websockets

Tags: websocket, xively

I am trying to subscribe to datastream updates via the xively-js javascript library.
However, all I am getting is a 503 error right after creating the websocket:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://api.xively.com:8080/' failed: Unexpected response code: 503

The same error is produced by the xively-js sample-app at 
http://xively.github.io/xively-js/sample-app/

Both IE10 and Chrome give the same result.
I can't seem to find any *working* xively websocket sample. Does somebody have any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question. It looks like non-secure websockets don't work for some reason.

The secure version `wss://api.xively.com:8094` is working fine.